# At times Google LVL fails with 'Error contacting licensing server.' Have other seen this?

Tags: android, google-play, android-lvl

My test app is very simple and almost identical to the LVL sample. And when it works, it works very well. Twice today however, I have gotten the app into an error state where the app reports that it cannot contact the licensing server.
At first I was unable to clear the error condition - even though I tried:

- Clear the data in 'Google Play Store'
- Reboot my tablet
- Reinstalled my Test app

None of these helped. 
With this error, adb logcat reported:

```
I/LicenseChecker( 7265): Binding to licensing service.
I/LicenseChecker( 7265): Calling checkLicense on service for com.DynaZu.Tracker.Prokey
I/LicenseChecker( 7265): Start monitoring timeout.
I/LicenseChecker( 7265): Received response.
I/LicenseChecker( 7265): Clearing timeout.
W/LicenseValidator( 7265): Error contacting licensing server.
D/LicenseChecker( 7265): Server Failure: ERROR_CONTACTING_SERVER
D/LicenseChecker( 7265): Android ID: 34ac09669bf32423
D/LicenseChecker( 7265): Time: 30 Dec 2012 05:43:31 GMT
```

What I finally did was change one byte in the 20 byte SALT used by the AESObfuscator passed into the LicenseChecker.  This change immediately resolved the issue. I hope this helps some with this issue.

Has anyone else seen this issue??  Does the Obfuscated data somehow get garbled?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it was a transient problem with the network or with the license server. Changing the salt value should not have any influence on that, it was just a coincidence.

Comment: I believe that this has Nothing to do with the license server since it never corrects itself once it gets into this state.  It's also clear that the changes to the SALT moves away from the problem (however it is cached) since then the persistent data must be dumped and a new set generated.   What is Strange is how this can come about.  That I would really like to know, but until it happens again, I can't determine how. What would be useful is a piece of code to dump out the persistent data. (Thanks for your answer @Henry)

Comment: But then why doesn't it ever correct itself -- what error is being cached??

Comment: Did you try to clear the data of the application (you just mentioned clearing data of play store)

Comment: I don't believe I did --- perhaps that would also help (I will try that when the problem resurfaces).  It seems in general that the LVL interaction with the Play Store server is a bit temperamental. I now have things working well today -- but sometimes I have noticed that one much just wait for a long time for things to clear up. Thanks for the suggestion.